# ₽ - правильное отображение в браузерах

Tags: css3, html5, utf-8

Попытался использовать символ рубля в html/css, результат не очень

```
.example::before {
    content: "\u20bd",
    ....
}
```

Вот такой код работает корректно на моем браузере Chrome в Win 7. Но на том же Хроме и Win 7 у другого человека не работает, и у кого-то еще на каком-то браузере тоже. У кого-то показывает квадратики, а у кого-то явления и похуже. Поискал и вяснил, что проблема в кодировках (наверно).

Можно ли как-то исправить ситуацию? или все же отказаться от использования "₽" и использовать "Руб."

Comment: проблема не в кодировках, а в отсутствии этого символа в старых шрифтах. можно использовать для знака рубля отдельный шрифт, где он есть, или выбрать такой шрифт для всего проекта. В новых системах/браузерах он подставляется системный тк не нашел его в вашем шрифте

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё верно в комментах отписали - пока поддержка оставляет желать лучшего, но шрифты обновляют уже. Ну, а пока, на крайний случай, грязный хак (раньше часто выручал):

```css
p { font: bold 3em 'Arial'; text-align: center; }

.rub {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0.26em;
  width: 0.4em;
  border-bottom: 0.11em solid #000;
}
```

```html
<p>Стоимость: 1000 <span class="rub">Р</span></p>
```

Comment: ну почему сразу грязный хак, нормальный хак :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT "грязный" потому, что не универсальный и каждый раз допиливать надо под конкретную задачу, т.е. шрифт.